# Xamarin Android - Google Map Marker always show the same info

Tags: android, android-intent, parse-platform, xamarin, xamarin.android

so what I'm trying to do is when a user tap on a Google Map Marker, an activity will show that will display all the information inside that marker. But the problem is, all markers shows the same result(which is the item in the first row of my parse.com database). I am currently using Xamarin for development. I will appreciate any answer. Thank you guys in advanced.

```
public async void getGeoPoint(){
        string getPlaceName, getPlacePrice, getPlaceAddress, getOwnerContact,   getRentalType, getOwnerName;

        string xx = autoCompleteTextView.Text;
        ParseQuery<ParseObject> query = ParseObject.GetQuery ("Rentals")
        .WhereEqualTo ("rentalCity", xx);
        IEnumerable<ParseObject> results = await query.FindAsync ();

        foreach(var temp in results){
             getLatitude = temp.Get<double> ("rentalLatitude");
             getLongitude = temp.Get<double> ("rentalLongitude");
            getPlaceName = temp.Get<string> ("rentalName");
             getPlacePrice = temp.Get<string> ("rentalPrice");
             getPlaceAddress = temp.Get<string> ("rentalFullAddress");
             getOwnerContact = temp.Get<string> ("ownerContactNo");
             getRentalType = temp.Get<string> ("rentalType");
             getOwnerName = temp.Get<string> ("ownerName");
            myMarker = map.AddMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                .SetPosition(new LatLng(getLatitude, getLongitude))
                .SetIcon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.FromResource(Resource.Drawable.edimeow))
                );
        }

        map.MarkerClick += (object sender, GoogleMap.MarkerClickEventArgs e) => {
            string selected = getPlaceName;
            var passToRentalProfile = new Intent (this, typeof(HostRentalProfileList));
            passToRentalProfile.PutExtra ("selected", selected);
            StartActivity (passToRentalProfile);
            this.Finish();
        };


        btnList.Click += (object sender, EventArgs e) => {
            var passToUserList = new Intent (this, typeof(UserListMode));
            passToUserList.PutExtra("arrData", xx);
            StartActivity(passToUserList);
            this.Finish();
        };

    }//getGeoPoint
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your `foreach` loop your enumerating all the results returned, and whilst you are adding a new map marker at different geo-positions, you are not storing any of the other details within the marker that is added.

Subsequently, when you enumerate the next result, your resetting your local variables to the new information.

Your `map.MarkerClick` is a generic handler that occurs for any map marker click.

Your attempting to reference `getPlaceName` which is set earlier, and will be equal to the last item in your results always.

You need to store these results in some collection and the add some id to a map marker that is created, so you can refer back to your original result to use, when they click on the map marker.

Answer (score 0):

I have something similar, where i need to display a custom message when a marker is clicked, I store it in a Dictionary and over the GoogleMap.IOnMarkerClickListener which will pass you the Marker that has been clicked.

public class MarkerManager : Java.Lang.Object, GoogleMap.IOnMarkerClickListener
    {

```
private readonly GoogleMap _map;

private Dictionary<Marker, int> _markerDictionary;

 public MarkerManager(GoogleMap map, BaseActivity activity)
    {
        _activity = activity;
        _map = map;
        _markerDictionary = new Dictionary<Marker, int>();
    }


    public void AddMarkerCallback(LatLng position, string title, string bodyText, int? icon, Action<int, Marker> callback,
        bool draggable = false, int id = 0)
    {
        var markerOptions = new MarkerOptions();
        markerOptions.SetPosition(position);
        markerOptions.SetTitle(title);
        markerOptions.SetSnippet(bodyText);
        markerOptions.Draggable(draggable);

        CallBack = callback;

        if (icon.HasValue)
        {
            markerOptions.InvokeIcon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.FromResource(icon.Value));
        }

        var marker = _map.AddMarker(markerOptions);
        _markerDictionary.Add(marker, id);

        _map.SetOnMarkerClickListener(this);
    }

    public void ClearMap()
    {
        if(_map != null)
        _map.Clear();

        _markerDictionary = new Dictionary<Marker, int>();
    }


    public bool OnMarkerClick(Marker p0)
    {
        p0.ShowInfoWindow();

        Console.WriteLine("maker click");

        HideMarkerAfterTime(p0);

        foreach (var i in _markerDictionary)
        {
            if (!i.Key.Equals(p0)) continue;
            if (CallBack == null) return true;

            SeletedMarkerId = i.Value;
            CallBack(i.Value, p0);
            return true;
        }

        if (CallBackLocation != null)
            CallBackLocation(p0.Position);

        return false;
    }


    /// <summary>
    /// The timer
    /// </summary>
    private System.Timers.Timer _timer;

    /// <summary>
    /// Hides the marker after time.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="p0">The p0.</param>
    /// <param name="miliSeconds">The mili seconds.</param>
    private void HideMarkerAfterTime(Marker p0, double miliSeconds = 3000)
    {
        //need to clean down timer object. if i click on another
        //icon wierd things happen
        if (_timer != null) _timer.Dispose();

        _timer = new System.Timers.Timer { Interval = miliSeconds };
        _timer.Start();
        _timer.Elapsed += (sender, args) => _activity.RunOnUiThread(() =>
        {
            p0.HideInfoWindow();
            _timer.Stop();
        });
    }
}
```